# Search for a repeated subtsring and print out all the string value only once in java

Tags: java, string, substring, contains

I have a log text file that shows the versions of an element e.g (Version software 219 build 23) which is repeated many times in the log. I want to print out the line that shows the version only once

so I thought I would search for the string that starts with the string (version)  and just print the entire line only once. in this case, search for string that contains (version) and then print the whole line.

the line that contains the version: Version software 219 build 23

String startsWith() or contains?

Any advise on how to implement this or any code examples I can follow?

Added an extract of the log file:

```
00:27:29:933 RFID UID bad len=0 Version software 219 build 23
00:33:03:378 No CAN0 errs to send
00:43:03:363 No CAN0 errs to send
00:55:01:522 GSM has turned off
00:55:01:522 Core Low Power Settings:
00:55:01:522 Mode: LPM_CPU_POWER_MODE_KINETIS_LLS
00:55:01:522 Wake up events:
00:55:01:522 LLWU_PE1 = 0x00 Mode wake up events from pins 0..3
00:55:01:522 LLWU_PE2 = 0x00 Mode wake up events from pins 4..7
00:55:01:538 LLWU_PE3 = 0x00 Mode wake up events from pins 8
00:55:55:726 Version software 219 build 23
```

Comment: please add sample log file content, which will help to understand

Comment: can you show _code_ what you end up so far

Comment: do you have your logs on unix box. if so use the grep utility. or use a similar utility in windows like find.

Comment: 00:27:29:933    RFID UID bad len=0 Version software 219 build 23
00:33:03:378    No CAN0 errs to send
00:43:03:363    No CAN0 errs to send
00:55:01:522    GSM has turned off
00:55:01:522    Core Low Power Settings:
00:55:01:522      Mode:      LPM_CPU_POWER_MODE_KINETIS_LLS 
00:55:01:522    Wake up events:
00:55:01:522      LLWU_PE1 = 0x00 Mode wake up events from pins 0..3
00:55:01:522      LLWU_PE2 = 0x00 Mode wake up events from pins 4..7
00:55:01:538      LLWU_PE3 = 0x00 Mode wake up events from pins 8
00:55:55:726    Version software 219 build 23

Comment: Just added an extract of the long. you can see the string (Version software 219 build 23) is repeated a couple of times but there a  few of them in the entire log

Comment: @hm9 comments don't preserve formatting. Presumably your log file is on a number of lines, but the comment has joined them all up. You should put the log contents in the question itself (click 'edit'), then highlight them and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: Ok I have done that. yes they are on separate line. thanks

Comment: I was thinking of something like this:      if (valuea.contains("Version software"))
         
         {
          
  
     
            
            System.out.println(valuea); (need to add something to print the rest of the string

Comment: If you do a software update, wouldn't you want to see the new software version in the log?

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be what you are asking for :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        Set<String> set=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C://abc.log"), "UTF-8");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                if(! line.contains("Version"))
                    continue;
                else {
                    String c[] = line.split(" ");
                    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                        if(c[i].equals("XDR2")) {
                            String r = "";
                            for(int k = i; k < i+4; k++){
                                r = r + c[k] + " ";
                            }
                            set.add(r);
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        for (String version : set) {
            System.out.println(version);
        }
    }
}
```

I just spitted the string to an array, after which ran a loop to check for "Version" and printed the next 4 letters including "Version".

```
Version software 219 build
```

Let me know if you don't understand the logic.

Comment: The question was edited just now. The update shows separate lines in the logs. The OP wants to print a line containing "Version" only once.

Comment: Yes thank you  @learner8269 similar concept and makes sense but the only 2 things are: i m checking a log file so instead of string a, i need to check the file content. 2) I only need to print the version once. if i do the loop it will print amny duplicate values

Comment: @hm9 : Edited  the answer as per changes made to question.

Comment: It doesnt like this line: for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){. Also instead of string a, is it possible to make it check the file instead? enter a file path since the log file is logged to a directory

Comment: @hm9 : Edited the answer again as per your requirement. Also for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()) is just the for each loop if you want u can use any other kind of loop to iterate over Map. I am using maps so I don't have to handle duplicates. Let java take care of that for me.

Comment: The last code you posted is what should do it. it just need to work, did it work on your set up?I m getting undefine contructor error for fileReader and not liking the freader.close

Comment: no such error, it worked fine. added the output too.

Comment: unable to move to chat so just posted again under answer. pz note I slightly changed your code to get rid of the errors but its not printing any output. your solution makes sense but kept getting errors. wonder if the one I posed could be fixed or adjusted so it works. thanks

Comment: Made an update as to what script I used to solve the problem. Please go through it.

Comment: ok but this is the error: Description Resource Path Location Type
Map.Entry is a raw type. References to generic type Map.Entry<K,V> should be parameterized Simple.java /selrcdemo/src/XDR1 line 33 Java Problem

Comment: Understood your issue we will keep things simple with LinkedHashSet then. I will update the answer

Comment: No errors now but nothing is printed. should it say contains rather than equal?

Comment: Provide the log file you are using. Because for me it worked.

Comment: Unable to attach the log file but provided an extract of the file below. It is saved with .txt extension and has several lines with the version repeated throughout the file

Comment: It was executed once and printed every row with version on it but it should only print it once. The log file is big so it get stuck in a loop then just print every row with the string value of version.

Comment: Check now and let me know if it is working without getting stuck.

Comment: Sorry. Its still stuck in the loop

Comment: how big is the log file by line count.

Comment: The file is quite big around 120000 lines, 5mb aproximately

Comment: it works if you have a short file with just a few lines but for a large file such as a log file, it just get stuck

Comment: may be it needs changing so that it just checks the first occurrence of the string then stops and print the out put instead of looping through the entire log file?

Comment: Why didn't you told before. Don't worry understood now that there is a memory blocking issue will update the code in a moment.

Comment: Updated the code, check now I believe it should not hang or freeze this time. If it does let me know.

Comment: it doent hang but it doesnt output anything. it works with a smaller file but not the log file.

Comment: I can email you the full log so you can see the format. One thing to note is that each line in the log starts with date time and then then another string as shown below:                                                                            00:02:54:024   Version software 219 build 23

Comment: Just mail me at anurag0510@outlook.com I will check it.

Comment: The logs you provided are working as expected just by replace "Version" with "<Your Starting Word With X>" and changing loop value to for(int k = i; k < i+4; k++). Will update the code again. Check please it is working for me as expected.

Comment: Check with the updated code above. And let me know if any issue arises as  after verifying the log every thing is as expected from my end.

Comment: Just wondering if I want to print the logging date time string at the very top of the log file (Logging started at 00:00:22 on 31/12/2017), do I have to create another hashset or is there an easy way to change the code and just print the string?

Comment: If there are multiple such lines just use hashset. Or else go with string if it is just a single starting line.